# Prevent multiple browsers installing the same PWA

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I have created a Progressive Web App and it can be installed on many different mobile browsers, be it Chrome (Android), Edge Mobile, or Opera Mobile.

My problem is as such, lets say I have Chrome and Opera on my phone. I installed the PWA from Chrome. Then I visit Opera and it also allows me to install the PWA.

So, how can I detect if the PWA is installed and, if possible, prevent other browsers from installing the PWA if detected?

I know that the `getInstalledRelatedApps()` can be used to detect if similar native app is installed. But I would like to detect is if similar PWA is installed before, is it even possible?

Comment: I know Edge originally knew if the chrome WebAPK was installed, but they stopped checking this. Since non-chrome browsers don't install a WebAPK, there is no way the other browsers would know if it is installed. Realistically, do most of your users use multiple browsers? Probably not.